# Solving PDE resembling the Airy equation

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

Hey I am trying to solve following PDE:

$\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}+Ax_2\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x_1}=\nu (\frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x_1^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x_2^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x_3^2})$

I tried using the seperation of variables as $Psi(x_1,x_2,x_3,t)=F_1(x_1)F_2(x_2)F_3(x_3)T(t)$

However I do find it diffult to solve this, since in the PDE it seems the dependency between $x_1,x_2$ is very linked... MAPLE also could not really help.

Any advice or someone who could provide me with an approach to solve this PDE?

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: What is the domain? What are the boundary conditions?

Comment: @RRL, thank you very much for your help:). The domain in $x_1$ is unbounded, meaning $[0,\infty]$, in $x_2$ direction it is bounded with [0,L] and in $x_3$ direction it is also unbounded; $[0,\infty]$. It is hard to describe the Boundary conditions, since I only have Boundary conditons fot the volicities, and this $\Phi$ is a function I constructed in order to solve for the volicities. For example this function $\Phi=\Delta u_2$, with $u_2(0)=0,u_2(L)=0$

Answer (score 1):

Using separation of variables, and by assuming $F_1(x_1)=e^{r_1x_1}$, $F_3(x_3)=e^{r_3x_3}$, $T(t)=e^{r_4t}$, you're left an ODE describing $F_2(x_2)$,
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d^2F_2}{\mathrm dx_2^2}+\left(r_1^2+r_3^2-\frac{r_4+Ar_1y}{\nu}\right)F_2=0,
\end{align}
whose solution is some sort of Airy function.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%27%27%2B%28a%2Bby%29f%28y%29%3D0

Comment: Hey @Eli,
Thank you very much. I highly appreciate your help :). Is it possible for $F_3(x_3)$ to be of trigonometric nature, hence $F_3(x_3)=sin(r_3 x_3)$? This would help me with the physical interpretation of this solution?

Comment: Hey, I found the solution as $ \Phi=(C_1Ai(\frac{-A a x_2-(\nu a^2-\nu c^2+d)}{\nu (\frac{A a}{\nu})^{\frac{1}{3}}})+C_2Bi(\frac{-A a x_2-(\nu a^2-\nu c^2+d)}{\nu (\frac{A a}{\nu})^{\frac{1}{3}}}))(C_3 sin(c x_3)+C_4 cos(c x_3))e^{a x_1}e^{-dT}$